# Imbedded CSS variable values

Tags: css

I am trying to learn about and work with CSS variables. I was wondering if it’s possible to nest several values inside a CSS variable to create a variable setting for a generic button to be used over and over.
Here’s my scenario:
I want to style a button that I will use repeatedly throughout my website. I have styled the button using variables like this:

```
:root {
    --button1: #777;
    --btnRadius: 7px;
    --btnColor: #fff;
    --padding: 12px;
}
.btn1 {
    background-color: var(--button1);
    border-radius: var(--btnRadius);
    color: var(--btnColor);
    padding: var(--padding);
}
```

In my “btn1” on the CSS sheet, I call all the values I want attributed to the button. Background color, font color, border radius and padding. This works fine.
However, I am trying to figure out how to put all those values into a single variable and simply call the variable in my “btn1” styling.
Something like this:

```
:root {
    --ButtonStyle {
        background-color: #777,
        border-radius: 7px,
        color: #fff,
        padding: 12px;
        }
}
.btn1 {
    var(--ButtonStyle);
}
```

However, this obviously is not working.
Is there a way to do this with variables in CSS?
Thanks.

Comment: no you cannot ...

Comment: Thanks Temani, so what is the point of variables, because it seems like it's just more code to write when I could just create a basic style for my buttons and give that CSS class to each button I create. Just curious. Like I said, I'm just learning about variables.

Comment: in your case you don't need variables since you define a value *one* time. It's like any programming language. If you want to use `5` in one place then use `5` but if that value will be used in different places, you define it as a variable to easily update it in one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and say you want to be able to change themes?
If so then just create another list of variables. Then switch the theme and you will basically reload your btn1 class with the new variables.

```js
document.getElementById('foo').onclick = function() {
  document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark");
}
```

```css
:root {
  --button1: #777;
  --btnRadius: 7px;
  --btnColor: #fff;
  --padding: 12px;
}

[data-theme="dark"] {
  --button1: #555;
  --btnColor: #000;
}

.btn1 {
  background-color: var(--button1);
  border-radius: var(--btnRadius);
  color: var(--btnColor);
  padding: var(--padding);
}

body {
  background-color: var(--btnColor);
}
```

```html
<body>

  <button id="foo" class="btn1">
Click Here to Change Theme
</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks bmiller, now I can see some justification for using variables in CSS.